# How to retrieve a picture set in ProfilePictureView and insert in an Sqlite database using a HashMap in android?

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I have set the `ProfilePictureview` with my FB profile pic. What I want to do is retrieve the profile pic from the ProfilePictureView and insert it in an `Sqlite` Database. My codes are as follows. And please guide me step by step.

```
 Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
          @Override
         public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(user!=null)
                    {
                    final String t1=user.getId();
                    final String t2=user.getName();
                    ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
                    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
                    profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());

                    int count=db.getme();
                    if(count==0)
                    {

                    map.put("uid",t1.toString());
                    map.put("name",t2.toString());
                    db.insertnewuser(map);
                    }
                    }
                }
            });
```

MyDatabase class:

```
  public void insertnewuser(HashMap<String, String> queryValues4) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values4 = new ContentValues();

    values4.put("fbuserid", queryValues4.get("name"));
    values4.put("fbname", queryValues4.get("uid"));


     database.insert("me", null, values4);
     database.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm really going to help you, but here's what I've done and got some problems.

There are two ways to get the profile picture:

This one:

`profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.selection_profile_pic);`

`ImageView fbImage = ((ImageView) profilePictureView.getChildAt(0));`

`Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fbImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

And this one:

`profilePictureView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);`
`profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());`

`Bitmap bitmap = profilePictureView.getDrawingCache();`

To add the bitmap to the database, I followed this tutorial here:

http://sunil-android.blogspot.com.br/2013/10/insert-and-retrieve-image-into-db.html

However, the profile picture that I got is actually the No User Logged Picture, like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWlLu.jpg

I guess you have to wait for the picture to be retrieved from Facebook before you try to get it. But since I'm doing it insided a newMeRequest callback method, I don't know what else I could do.

Did you manage to do it after all?

Comment: getChildAt(0) and getDrawingCache() only return the default profile pic.  It seems like Facebook is deliberately blocking the ability to convert  a profile picture to a bitmap.